# Matplotlib--scatter plot with half filled markers

Tags: matplotlib, marker, scatter

Question:  Using a scatter plot in matplotlib, is there a simple way get a half-filled marker?

I know half-filled markers can easily be done using a line plot, but I would like to use 'scatter' because I want to use marker size and color (i.e., alternate marker face color) to represent other data. (I believe this will be easier with a scatter plot since I want to automate making a large number of plots from a large data set.)

I can't seem to make half-filled markers properly using a scatter plot. That is to say, instead of a half-filled marker, the plot shows half of a marker. I've been using matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle, but that seems to only get me halfway there. I'm able to get following output using the code below.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

plt.scatter(1, 1, marker=MarkerStyle('o', fillstyle='full'), edgecolors='k', s=500)
plt.scatter(2, 2, marker=MarkerStyle('o', fillstyle='left'), edgecolors='k', s=500)
plt.scatter(3, 3, marker=MarkerStyle('o', fillstyle='right'), edgecolors='k', s=500)
plt.scatter(4, 4, marker=MarkerStyle('o', fillstyle='top'), edgecolors='k', s=500)
plt.scatter(5, 5, marker=MarkerStyle('o', fillstyle='bottom'), edgecolors='k', s=500)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please see [Marker fill styles](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#filled-markers)

Comment: The examples on that page use plot.  Scatter plot doesn't seem to have fillstyle as one its parameters.  Maybe I'm missing something...?

Comment: And why can't you use plot with `linestyle="None"`?

Comment: I was intending to use the size (and possibly alternate face color) to show other data in the data set.  I was thinking that scatter would be better for those purposes.

Comment: There is `markersize` for the plot approach. I see one advantage for scatter: One can pass an array for color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I don't see why you have to use `plt.scatter` but if you want to, you can fake a combined marker:

```
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#data generation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(1, 20, n), 
      "Y": np.random.randint(10, 30, n), 
      "S": np.random.randint(50, 500, n), 
      "C1": np.random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"], n),
      "C2": np.random.choice(["yellow", "grey"], n)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(df.X, df.Y, s=df.S, c=df.C1, edgecolor="black", marker=MarkerStyle("o", fillstyle="right"))
ax.scatter(df.X, df.Y, s=df.S, c=df.C2, edgecolor="black", marker=MarkerStyle("o", fillstyle="left"))
    
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

This works, of course, also for continuous data:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(1, 20, n), 
      "Y": np.random.randint(10, 30, n), 
      "S": np.random.randint(100, 1000, n), 
      "C1": np.random.randint(1, 100, n),
      "C2": np.random.random(n)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

im1 = ax.scatter(df.X, df.Y, s=df.S, c=df.C1, edgecolor="black", marker=MarkerStyle("o", fillstyle="right"), cmap="autumn")
im2 = ax.scatter(df.X, df.Y, s=df.S, c=df.C2, edgecolor="black", marker=MarkerStyle("o", fillstyle="left"), cmap="winter")
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(im1, ax=ax)
cbar1.set_label("right half", rotation=90)
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(im2, ax=ax)
cbar2.set_label("left half", rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

[But be reminded that `plt.plot` with marker definitions might be faster for large-scale datasets](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter): `The plot function will be faster for scatterplots where markers don't vary in size or color.`